# Query value of hybrid_method

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to retrieve only "new" models.  A model is "new" based on the value of the `is_new` hybrid_method.

I think since I'm dealing with objects instead of instances this method won't work for me.  I think what I need is an expression but I'm unsure how to write one for this use case.  I basically just want models that were created less than 30 days ago.

**MyModel**

```
@hybrid_method
def is_new(self):
    future = self.created_at + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    if datetime.datetime.now() < future:
        return True
    return False
```

**Query**

```
MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.is_new() == True).all()
```

**Error**

`TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an expression.  An expression must return a boolean value.  I have below a hybrid_property for reading from an instance and an expression for querying against the database.

**Model**

```
@hybrid_property
def is_new_product(self):
    future = self.created_at + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    if datetime.datetime.now() < future:
        return True
    return False

@is_new_product.expression
def is_new_product(cls):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    return cls.created_at + delta > datetime.datetime.now()
```

**Query**

```
ProductModel.query.filter(ProductModel.is_new_product==True).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `hybrid_method`, you need to filter by the return value of the method.

```
MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.is_new()).all()
```

As an alternative, since you aren't passing any arguments to `is_new`, you can use `hybrid_property` instead. That will allow you to perform the comparison.

```
@hybrid_property
def is_new(self):
    ...

MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.is_new == True).all()
```

Comment: The problem with using a hybrid_property is this part: `if datetime.datetime.now() < future:`.  It raises the same boolean error.  I need to be using `func` so that instead of a value I have an expression that can be evaluated.